# Differ between 'softtabstop' and 'expandtab' options in function

Tags: vimrc, options

If you use of `softtabstop` and `expandtab` options in vary ways and try to test them, these options are opposite in function (at least as I think).

`et` option will produce the appropriate number of space when we press TAB key and when we press BS the spaces will delete one by one in the other hand when we set `sts` and press BS it will delete a tab (not spaces one by one).
Thus setting `et` and `sts` option in vimrc together isn't a good idea because they will break their effect together.

Now am I thinking right? (If not please let me know how they are differ in function and behaviour.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. `sts` and `et` options have distinct functions and are not mutually exclusive.

With `softtabstop` and `noexpandtab`, vim will insert a *mixture of tabs and spaces*, to make it up to the `sts` value.  How many tabs are inserted depends on `tabstop`, for example `ts=3`, `sts=4`, vim will insert one tab and one space, for a total of 4 spaces-equivalent.

With `softtabstop` and `expandtab`, vim will insert the `sts` number of spaces.

In both cases, backspacing still works as though you had inserted a tab which is `sts` wide.

vim's behavior and number of indent-related options is perhaps surprising, but this is not merely an "academic" discussion.  For a real example, see the vim source code, which uses indents of four spaces-equivalent but `tabstop=8`.  So, lines indented once get four spaces in front, lines indented twice get a tab, and lines indented thrice get a tab then four spaces.  In this case, one *might* prefer `set sts=4 sw=4 ts=8`.  When pressing `<tab>` twice, vim will insert a real tab instead of spaces.  Note also this answer does not discuss interaction with the `shiftwidth` or `smarttab` options.